# update only records that are non empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query, which i use to update a table.
The issue is, i need to update only values different from "undefined"

With the help of someone here i got to this query:

```
$sqlStart="UPDATE forma SET ";
$sql="";
if (!empty($postDyqani_pergjegjes)) $sql += " dyqani_pergjegjes='$postDyqani_pergjegjes',";
if (!empty($postEmri)) $sql += "  emri='$postEmri',";
if (!empty($postKlienti)) $sql += "  klienti='$postKlienti',";
if (!empty($postTelefoni)) $sql += "  telefoni='$postTelefoni,'";
if (!empty($postMontim)) $sql += "  montim='$postMontim',";
if (!empty($postAdresa)) $sql += "  adresa='$postAdresa',";
if (!empty($postData_e_shitjes)) $sql += "  data_e_shitjes='$postData_e_shitjes',";
if (!empty($postDifekti)) $sql += "  difekti='$postDifekti',";
if (!empty($postTekniku_emer)) $sql += "  tekniku_emer='$postTekniku_emer',";
if (!empty($postTekniku_mesazh)) $sql += "  tekniku_mesazh='$postTekniku_mesazh',";
if (!empty($postData_fillim)) $sql += "  data_fillim='$postData_fillim',";
if (!empty($postData_mbarim)) $sql += "  data_mbarim='$postData_mbarim',";
if (!empty($postData)) $sql += "  data='$postData',";
if (!empty($postStatus)) $sql += "  status='$postStatus',";
// replace the last `,` for `;`
if ($sql != "") {
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ";";

    // replace the last `,` for `;`
    // run sql command
    echo $sqlCommand = $sqlStart.$sql;
    $result=mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error()) ;

} else {
}
```

It won't execute though..
Please give me a hand on this..
if i print the variables most of them result to be `undefined`
Thanks

Comment: "undefined"? There's no such value in PHP or MySQL. Please describe what you're trying to do better. Maybe `... WHERE something IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: the idea is, the update query will be flexibele, so some variables even if they are in the query, might not have a value and when i print them, it says undefined

Comment: can u do echo $sqlStart;exit; before 'if' and show me.

Comment: i DID THAT.. BUT I DIDN'T HAVE ANYTHING..

Comment: Did you try changing that `+=`, which is for *addition*, to `.=`, which is for *string concatenation*, as pointed out by @Kao?

Comment: yes i did, but nothing changed

Comment: It absolutely has something to do with the $sql variable, it will return empty!

Comment: Is there something in any one of the $postData variables? Are they **ALL** empty?

Comment: No, most of them are not empty, the others if i print them, they say undefined

Comment: I assume that it actually reaches the line that says: `echo $sqlCommand = $sqlStart.$sql;` Could you show us the output of that line?

Comment: that's the point, i get the $sql as empty, which can't be..

Comment: which means, there's something with the if clauses

Comment: try to change empty to isset

Comment: done that.. already done that...
i'm losing patience :(

Comment: @al_alb - from where you variables are coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things broken with your approach; first of all, += won't do what you think it does for PHP strings, and will probably make everything end up as the value 0. Use .= to concatenate a string to an existing string:

```
$foo = '123';
$foo .= 'abc';

// $foo == '123abc'
```

Second, without any more information about where your variables are coming from, it'll be hard to say what's going the wrong way. If you have a field named 'Dyqani_pergjegjes', the correct way to reference it will be to use `$_POST['Dyqani_pergjegjes']`.

In addition you need to escape strings that you want to use in an SQL query, to avoid SQL injection exploits and other possible bugs (or use prepared statements in mysqli or by using PDO) if you want do solve it properly):

```
difekti='". mysql_real_escape_string($postDifekti) . "'
```

You're also missing a condition for your UPDATE-statement, so in it's current form it'll change all the rows in the database. Probably not what you want. And you do not need to add a ";" at the end of the statement - this is implicit when performing a query, and is generally advised against.